# RichEdit identify image (WINE/MacOS)

Tags: bitmap, rtf, ole, wine, richedit

I would like to run an application under the WINE, but there are some issues with richedit. It is necessary to insert a bitmap. A variant with OleCreateStaticFromData->IRichEditOle::InsertObject does not work on the WINE, but it is possible to insert a picture using GetRichEditCtrl::StreamIn and bitmap that was converted to RTF.
There is one more task, still need to distinguish bitmaps in the text. In the original approach IRichEditOle::InsertObject takes REOBJECT.dwUser parameter which is very convenient to store identifier (which can then be accessed via IRichEditOle::GetObject).

Is there another way to get or identify image in RichEdit?